# Alternatives to HTMLhelp in VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, chm, html-help

I'm porting an some code to VS2013, and ran across a linker error today:

htmlhelp.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2026:  module unsafe for SAFESEH image

So, I'm faced with two alternatives:  Find an htmlhelp.lib that's compatible, or find an alternative.

Any suggestions on either?

Comment: Or I can just turn off SAFESEH on my project (since it obviously never had it before), but I'm not sure what the implications of that are either.

Comment: No repro whatsoever.  Do document which htmlhelp.lib you are linking.

Comment: Check answers in this question: [module unsafe for SAFESEH image C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10599940/113116)

Comment: @HansPassant I wasn't aware there were multiple versions of the library.  It's the one from the HTML Help workshop, but it might be older than that.  Which version did you link with VS2013 that didn't give a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, more info is available here on SAFESEH:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a89h429(v=vs.110).aspx

@HansPassant above pointed out that he couldn't repro, which sent me searching.
I had been using the version installed with the ancient HTML Help workshop (ca 1999), and have now linked with the one from the windows SDK
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A which is a bit more modern, and doesn't show the problem.