# CMake zlib build on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, cmake, zlib

I'm trying to build zlib 1.2.8 for Windows using CMake, but I get build errors that I don't know how to fix.
Here's my CMake GUI:

[image]

This generates without errors, but when I build the resulting solution. I get this error:

> 2>------ Build started: Project: zlib, Configuration: Release x64 ------
>   2> Creating library C:/Users/erik/Documents/zlib/1.2.8/project/zlib-1.2.8-vc10/Release/zlib.lib and object C:/Users/erik/Documents/zlib/1.2.8/project/zlib-1.2.8-vc10/Release/zlib.exp
>   2> inflate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol inflate_fast referenced in function inflate
>   2>infback.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol inflate_fast
>   2>C:\Users\erik\Documents\zlib\1.2.8\project\zlib-1.2.8-vc10\Release\zlib.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I don't know how I can fix this, so I appreciate any help.

Comment: Looking at the CMakeLists.txt file, I'm not sure what the problem with CMake is here. You might try building the contributed "zlibvc.sln" Visual Studio solution in the "contrib/vstudio/vc10" directory as a possible remedy. There appear to be Release, ReleaseWithoutAsm and Debug configurations for all three targets: Win32 (x86), x64, and Itanium. Oh, and there's also the Nmake file named "Makefile.msc" in the "win32" directory that you can build from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.

Comment: You can download a pre-compiled version of zlib. Just in case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/Win64Compilation a very similar error means:

> This means you have a typo in either -DASMV -DASMINF or your OBJ="inffasx64.obj gvmat64.obj inffas8664.obj" since inflate_fast is defined in inffas8664.c.

---

I was able to successfully build with a simple:

```
mkdir C:\Builds\zlib; cd C:\Builds\zlib
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013" -A x64 D:\Downloads\zlib-1.2.8\
cmake --build .
```

I looked at my cmake cache and I see that AMD64 is set to false, unlike what your cmake-gui window shows. Setting it to true it results all kinds of build errors for me, though not the ones you show.

CMakeLists.txt says this option is to enable an AMD64 assembly implementation. Just doing without this seems to be the easiest solution.

Comment: Unchecking AMD64 seems to work. I was under the impression that this had to be checked in order to build 64-bit.

Comment: @elveatles With CMake the way to specify 64-bit builds is generator specific and shouldn't depend on the project. (AMD64 is not one of the 'built-in' cmake variables, it's custom for the zlib project); with the Visual Studio generator you set the platform to x64 with `-A x64`. With Ninja you just configure the shell you run cmake from with a 64-bit tool chain. E.g. run CMake -G Ninja from the Visual Studio 64-bit command line.

Comment: Note: this is just a **workaround**. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 11):

You need **contrib\masmx64\inffas8664.c** included in visual studio project file.
This file contains `inflate_fast` function which calls corresponding `asm` functions.

Comment: Do you know why it is not included by default?

Comment: I have no idea. But 'contrib' means It is not maintained by zlib author, I think.

Comment: You got it right. You can find the **cause** in my answer

Answer (score 9):

#### Important note

***contrib/masmx** directories were removed** back in 2017 (at answer time I was working on the *v1.2.11* *.zip* file which contains them), so everything below **no longer applies** (*OOTB*). 
But their references were **not** removed (at least not from all places), so if they're enabled (from *CMake*), **build will fail**.

However, I submitted **[[GitHub]: madler/zlib - Re enable ASM speedups on Win](https://github.com/madler/zlib/pull/701)**, (**rejected** on *221007*) so everything below **does apply** (again). 
For possible ways to benefit from the patch (**once / if it's accepted**), check [[SO]: How to change username of job in print queue using python & win32print (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71684828/4788546) (at the end).

Applied the above patch to (current) *master* branch:

- Built for:

  - *064bit* / *032bit*
  - *Release* / *Debug*
  - With / without *ASM* speedups
- Ran *minigzip.exe* (which links to *zlib(d).dll*):

  - On binary / text file
  - Methods: inflate / deflate
  - Levels: 1, 5, 9

Used following script to go through all configurations, run and aggregate results.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import hashlib as hl
import os
import shutil
import subprocess as sp
import sys
import time
from pprint import pprint as pp


ARCHS = (
    "pc064",
    "pc032",
)


def print_file_data(file, level=0):
    st = os.stat(file)
    header = "  " * level
    print("{:s}File: {:s}\n{:s}  Size: {:d}, CTime: {:s}".format(header, file, header, st.st_size, time.ctime(st.st_ctime)))


def main(*argv):
    verbose = False
    build_dir = os.getcwd() #os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    if argv:
        file = argv[0]
        if "-v" in argv:
            verbose = True
    else:
        file = "file.onnx"
        #file = "bigfile.txt"
        #file = "enwik8"
    file_test = file + ".test"
    file_gz = file_test + ".gz"
    shutil.copy(file, file_test)
    md5_src = hl.md5(open(file_test, mode="rb").read()).hexdigest()
    print_file_data(file_test)
    data = {}
    for arch in ARCHS:
        if verbose:
            print("Arch: {:s}".format(arch))
        ad = {}
        for typ in ("plain", "masm"):
            if verbose:
                print("  Type: {:s}".format(typ))
            mg = os.path.join(build_dir, "_build", arch, typ, "minigzip.exe")
            for level in (1, 5, 9):
                shutil.copy(file, file_test)
                if verbose:
                    print("\n    Compress (level {:d})".format(level))
                proc = sp.Popen([mg, "-{:d}".format(level), file_test])
                time_start = time.time()
                proc.communicate()
                elapsed = time.time() - time_start
                if verbose:
                    print("    Took {:.3f} seconds".format(elapsed))
                ad.setdefault("level {:d}".format(level), {}).setdefault("inflate", {})[typ] = elapsed
                if verbose:
                    print_file_data(file_gz, level=2)
                if verbose:
                    print("    Decompress")
                proc = sp.Popen([mg, "-d", file_gz])
                time_start = time.time()
                proc.communicate()
                elapsed = time.time() - time_start
                if verbose:
                    print("    Took {:.3f} seconds".format(elapsed))
                ad.setdefault("level {:d}".format(level), {}).setdefault("deflate", {})[typ] = elapsed
                if verbose:
                    print_file_data(file_test, level=2)
                if hl.md5(open(file_test, mode="rb").read()).hexdigest() != md5_src:
                    print("!!! File hashes differ !!!")
        data[arch] = ad
    pp(data, indent=2, sort_dicts=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029505121]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py file.onnx
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.'level 9':ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> File: file.onnx.test
>   Size: 255890833, CTime: Sat Sep  3 02:03:05 2022
> { 'pc064': { 'level 1': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 12.552296161651611,
>                                        'masm': 11.09960412979126},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 1.802419900894165,
>                                        'masm': 1.8380048274993896}},
>              'level 5': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 13.694978713989258,
>                                        'masm': 12.098156213760376},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 1.756164312362671,
>                                        'masm': 1.7628483772277832}},
>              'level 9': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 13.969024419784546,
>                                        'masm': 12.125015497207642},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 1.7450010776519775,
>                                        'masm': 1.756005048751831}}},
>   'pc032': { 'level 1': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 13.748999118804932,
>                                        'masm': 11.81002926826477},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 1.9236936569213867,
>                                        'masm': 2.3493638038635254}},
>              'level 5': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 15.036035299301147,
>                                        'masm': 12.898797512054443},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 1.8580067157745361,
>                                        'masm': 2.282176971435547}},
>              'level 9': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 15.134005308151245,
>                                        'masm': 12.89007306098938},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 1.8709957599639893,
>                                        'masm': 2.2773334980010986}}}}
>
> Done.
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029505121]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py enwik8.txt
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.'level 9':ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> File: enwik8.txt.test
>   Size: 100000000, CTime: Tue Sep  6 00:33:20 2022
> { 'pc064': { 'level 1': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 1.9976372718811035,
>                                        'masm': 1.9259986877441406},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 0.7285704612731934,
>                                        'masm': 0.7076430320739746}},
>              'level 5': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 4.5627357959747314,
>                                        'masm': 4.003000020980835},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 0.6933917999267578,
>                                        'masm': 0.6450159549713135}},
>              'level 9': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 8.079626083374023,
>                                        'masm': 6.618978977203369},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 0.7049713134765625,
>                                        'masm': 0.6319396495819092}}},
>   'pc032': { 'level 1': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 2.1649997234344482,
>                                        'masm': 2.1139981746673584},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 0.7583539485931396,
>                                        'masm': 0.8125534057617188}},
>              'level 5': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 5.03799843788147,
>                                        'masm': 4.2109808921813965},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 0.8489999771118164,
>                                        'masm': 0.6870477199554443}},
>              'level 9': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 7.9073097705841064,
>                                        'masm': 7.512087821960449},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 0.7378275394439697,
>                                        'masm': 0.7450006008148193}}}}
>
> Done.
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029505121]> cd dbg
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029505121\dbg]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ../code00.py ../file.onnx
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.'level 9':ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> File: ../file.onnx.test
>   Size: 255890833, CTime: Tue Sep  6 00:37:51 2022
> { 'pc064': { 'level 1': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 25.337001085281372,
>                                        'masm': 22.544013023376465},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 3.915001153945923,
>                                        'masm': 2.3709957599639893}},
>              'level 5': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 28.28699827194214,
>                                        'masm': 24.88018822669983},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 3.846531867980957,
>                                        'masm': 2.2239699363708496}},
>              'level 9': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 28.81813645362854,
>                                        'masm': 23.6450355052948},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 3.9910058975219727,
>                                        'masm': 2.302088737487793}}},
>   'pc032': { 'level 1': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 24.923137664794922,
>                                        'masm': 20.991183042526245},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 3.7310261726379395,
>                                        'masm': 2.6056015491485596}},
>              'level 5': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 27.760021209716797,
>                                        'masm': 22.589048624038696},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 3.566000461578369,
>                                        'masm': 2.55342698097229}},
>              'level 9': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 28.245535135269165,
>                                        'masm': 22.70799994468689},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 3.553999423980713,
>                                        'masm': 2.5700416564941406}}}}
>
> Done.
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029505121\dbg]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ../code00.py ../enwik8.txt
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.'level 9':ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> File: ../enwik8.txt.test
>   Size: 100000000, CTime: Tue Sep  6 00:39:59 2022
> { 'pc064': { 'level 1': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 4.711355447769165,
>                                        'masm': 4.008531808853149},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 1.4210000038146973,
>                                        'masm': 0.9230430126190186}},
>              'level 5': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 8.914000034332275,
>                                        'masm': 6.604032516479492},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 1.3359959125518799,
>                                        'masm': 0.8460018634796143}},
>              'level 9': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 13.503999948501587,
>                                        'masm': 9.228030920028687},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 1.328040599822998,
>                                        'masm': 0.8240146636962891}}},
>   'pc032': { 'level 1': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 4.435391664505005,
>                                        'masm': 3.933983087539673},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 1.3369977474212646,
>                                        'masm': 0.9399752616882324}},
>              'level 5': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 8.48900055885315,
>                                        'masm': 6.599977731704712},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 1.2629964351654053,
>                                        'masm': 0.8410165309906006}},
>              'level 9': { 'inflate': { 'plain': 12.677618026733398,
>                                        'masm': 9.191060781478882},
>                           'deflate': { 'plain': 1.251995325088501,
>                                        'masm': 0.8130028247833252}}}}
>
> Done.
> ```

As seen, for release builds (that most people are interested in), the speed gain using the speedups is not that great (sometimes it's even slower than the *C* code). This (combined with the lack of maintenance) was one of the reasons for disabling them.

---

#### Original answer

While playing with assembler speedups, I discovered that the issue is reproducible on the (currently) latest version: ***v1.2.11*** ([[GitHub]: madler/zlib - ZLIB DATA COMPRESSION LIBRARY](https://github.com/madler/zlib)).

This error happens **only** (obviously, *OS*: *Win*, build toolchain: *VStudio* and assembly speedups enabled) for:

- *CMake* build (works *OK* for *"${ZLIB_SRC_DIR}/win32/Makefile.msc"*)
- *x64* (*AMD64* (*pc064*)) architecture (works *OK* for *x86* (*pc032*))

Below is a "*callstack*" (*top -> down* is equivalent to *outer -> inner*) during decompression.

1. Normal case:

   1. *inflate* (*inflate.c*)
   2. *inflate_fast* (*inffast.c*)
   3. ...
2. Assembler case:

   1. *inflate* (*inflate.c*)
   2. *inflate_fast* (*contrib/masmx64/inffast8664.c*)
   3. *inffas8664fnc* (*contrib/masmx64/inffasx64.asm*)
   4. ...

#### Problem:

***#2.2.*** is missing (***"${ZLIB_SRC_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt"* doesn't know anything about *inffast8664.c***), so the chain is broken, leading to invalid (incomplete) data to build library.

#### Solution:

Make *CMakeLists.txt* aware of that file, and that is by adding:

```cmake
set(ZLIB_SRCS
    ${ZLIB_SRCS}
    contrib/masmx64/inffas8664.c
)
```

at *line **~#158*** (enclosed by `if(MSVC)` and `elseif (AMD64)` conditionals).

Posting full changes as well.

*zlib-1.2.11-msvc_x64_asm_speedups.diff*:

```diff
--- CMakeLists.txt.orig 2017-01-15 08:29:40.000000000 +0200
+++ CMakeLists.txt  2018-09-03 13:41:00.314805100 +0300
@@ -79,10 +79,10 @@
 endif()
 
 set(ZLIB_PC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/zlib.pc)
-configure_file( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/zlib.pc.cmakein
-       ${ZLIB_PC} @ONLY)
-configure_file(    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/zconf.h.cmakein
-       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/zconf.h @ONLY)
+configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/zlib.pc.cmakein
+        ${ZLIB_PC} @ONLY)
+configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/zconf.h.cmakein
+        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/zconf.h @ONLY)
 include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
 
 
@@ -136,30 +136,34 @@
         set(ZLIB_ASMS contrib/amd64/amd64-match.S)
     endif ()
 
-   if(ZLIB_ASMS)
-       add_definitions(-DASMV)
-       set_source_files_properties(${ZLIB_ASMS} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE C COMPILE_FLAGS -DNO_UNDERLINE)
-   endif()
+    if(ZLIB_ASMS)
+        add_definitions(-DASMV)
+        set_source_files_properties(${ZLIB_ASMS} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE C COMPILE_FLAGS -DNO_UNDERLINE)
+    endif()
 endif()
 
 if(MSVC)
     if(ASM686)
-       ENABLE_LANGUAGE(ASM_MASM)
+        ENABLE_LANGUAGE(ASM_MASM)
         set(ZLIB_ASMS
-           contrib/masmx86/inffas32.asm
-           contrib/masmx86/match686.asm
-       )
+            contrib/masmx86/inffas32.asm
+            contrib/masmx86/match686.asm
+        )
     elseif (AMD64)
-       ENABLE_LANGUAGE(ASM_MASM)
+        ENABLE_LANGUAGE(ASM_MASM)
         set(ZLIB_ASMS
-           contrib/masmx64/gvmat64.asm
-           contrib/masmx64/inffasx64.asm
-       )
+            contrib/masmx64/gvmat64.asm
+            contrib/masmx64/inffasx64.asm
+        )
+        set(ZLIB_SRCS
+            ${ZLIB_SRCS}
+            contrib/masmx64/inffas8664.c
+        )
     endif()
 
-   if(ZLIB_ASMS)
-       add_definitions(-DASMV -DASMINF)
-   endif()
+    if(ZLIB_ASMS)
+        add_definitions(-DASMV -DASMINF)
+    endif()
 endif()
 
 # parse the full version number from zlib.h and include in ZLIB_FULL_VERSION
```

The above is a *diff*. See [[SO]: Run / Debug a Django application's UnitTests from the mouse right click context menu in PyCharm Community Edition? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989490/4788546) (**Patching *UTRunner*** section) for how to apply patches on *Win* (basically, every line that starts with **one "+"** sign goes in, and every line that starts with **one "-"** sign goes out). 
I also submitted this patch: [[GitHub]: madler/zlib - Ms VisualStudio - Assembler speedups on x64](https://github.com/madler/zlib/pull/376), but then I closed it, as it's contained in the one at the beginning.

**Output**:

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029505121\build\x64>"c:\Install\Google\Android_SDK\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe" -G "NMake Makefiles" -DAMD64=ON "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029505121\src\zlib-1.2.11"
> -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
> -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Install/x86/Microsoft/Visual Studio Community/2015/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe
> -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Install/x86/Microsoft/Visual Studio Community/2015/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe -- works
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
> -- Looking for sys/types.h
> -- Looking for sys/types.h - found
> -- Looking for stdint.h
> -- Looking for stdint.h - found
> -- Looking for stddef.h
> -- Looking for stddef.h - found
> -- Check size of off64_t
> -- Check size of off64_t - failed
> -- Looking for fseeko
> -- Looking for fseeko - not found
> -- Looking for unistd.h
> -- Looking for unistd.h - not found
> -- Renaming
> --     E:/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q029505121/src/zlib-1.2.11/zconf.h
> -- to 'zconf.h.included' because this file is included with zlib
> -- but CMake generates it automatically in the build directory.
> -- The ASM_MASM compiler identification is MSVC
> -- Found assembler: C:/Install/x86/Microsoft/Visual Studio Community/2015/VC/bin/amd64/ml64.exe
> -- Configuring done
> -- Generating done
> -- Build files have been written to: E:/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q029505121/build/x64
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029505121\build\x64>"c:\Install\Google\Android_SDK\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe" --build . --target zlibstatic
> Scanning dependencies of target zlibstatic
> [  5%] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/adler32.obj
> adler32.c
> [ 10%] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/compress.obj
> compress.c
> [ 15%] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/crc32.obj
> crc32.c
> [ 21%] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/deflate.obj
> deflate.c
> Assembler code may have bugs -- use at your own risk
> [ 26%] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/gzclose.obj
> gzclose.c
> [ 31%] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/gzlib.obj
> gzlib.c
> [ 36%] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/gzread.obj
> gzread.c
> [ 42%] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/gzwrite.obj
> gzwrite.c
> [ 47%] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/inflate.obj
> inflate.c
> [ 52%] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/infback.obj
> infback.c
> [ 57%] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/inftrees.obj
> inftrees.c
> [ 63%] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/inffast.obj
> inffast.c
> Assembler code may have bugs -- use at your own risk
> [ 68%] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/trees.obj
> trees.c
> [ 73%] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/uncompr.obj
> uncompr.c
> [ 78%] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/zutil.obj
> zutil.c
> [ 84%] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/contrib/masmx64/inffas8664.obj
> inffas8664.c
> [ 89%] Building ASM_MASM object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/contrib/masmx64/gvmat64.obj
> Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler (x64) Version 14.00.24210.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
>  Assembling: E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029505121\src\zlib-1.2.11\contrib\masmx64\gvmat64.asm
> [ 94%] Building ASM_MASM object CMakeFiles/zlibstatic.dir/contrib/masmx64/inffasx64.obj
> Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler (x64) Version 14.00.24210.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
>  Assembling: E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q029505121\src\zlib-1.2.11\contrib\masmx64\inffasx64.asm
> [100%] Linking C static library zlibstatic.lib
> [100%] Built target zlibstatic
> ```

**Notes**:

- I am using *VStudio **2015***
- Regarding the above output:

  - To keep the output as small as possible, I am only building the *static* version

    - For the same reason (and also to keep it as just text), I'm building for ***"NMake Makefiles"*** (*CmdLine* build)
  - *inffas8664.c* is being built (somewhere near the end)
- You could also disable assembler speedups (by ***unchecking*** *AMD64* in *CMake-GUI*), but that would be just a workaround
- I did some rough tests (by far, I'm not claiming these results to be general), and the performance improvement of the assembler implementation over the standard one (*Debug* versions) was (a percent below is the **ratio between times took to perform the same operation** (with / without) speedups):

  - Compress: ***~86%***
  - Decompress: ***~62%***

---

#### Update *#0*

[[GitHub]: madler/zlib - ASM zlib build on Windows gives erroneous results (@madler's comment)](https://github.com/madler/zlib/issues/41#issuecomment-125848075) states (**emphasis** is mine):

> What assembly code is being used? There are a few in zlib's contrib directory. By the way, the stuff in the **contrib directory is not part of zlib**. It is just there as a convenience and is supported (or not) by those third-party contributors. What I will do is simply remove the offending code from the next distribution.

So does the compile warning (that everyone must have seen (and most likely ignored)):

> ```
> Assembler code may have bugs -- use at your own risk
> ```

Apparently, assembler speedups and *VStudio* don't (didn't) get along very well. More, on *x86* (*pc032*), there are some issues:

- A nasty one is a *SegFault* (*Access Violation*) during decompression. For that, [[GitHub]: madler/zlib - inffas32.asm struct/enum binding to zlib 1.2.9](https://github.com/madler/zlib/pull/369) (also included in the one at the beginning) is needed
- **Might no longer apply**: one fix is proposed by [[SO]: module unsafe for SAFESEH image C++ (@NayanaAdassuriya's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47508240/4788546) (although it's not directly related to the question). In short, *inffas32.asm* and *linker*'s option [[MS.Docs]: /SAFESEH (Image has Safe Exception Handlers)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/9a89h429(v=vs.140)) don't match. To get rid of it, either:

  - Disable the option (enabled by default on *x86 Release*)
  - Pass the ***/safeseh*** option to the assembler (*ml.exe*)
  - Declare one in *asm*

  Since I use *CMake* to build for *CmdLine*, I found a workaround for this. After *CMakeFiles* generation (but **before** the build), I specify it:

  - In the *flags.make* file (***ASM_MASM_FLAGS***)
  - Since I build a *static* lib (and for *Debug* builds I need the symbols as well), I also change [[MS.Docs]: /Z7, /Zi, /ZI (Debug Information Format)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/958x11bc(v=vs.140)), so I modify the same file (*C_FLAGS*)

  I'm sure that *CMake* offers a way of doing the above in a proper manner, but I didn't find it (nor did I investigate thoroughly)

After fixing them, everything works fine, and the performance improvements are similar to *pc064*.

---

In case anyone needs them, I've built and placed binaries at **[[GitHub]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - (master) Prebuilt-Binaries/ZLib](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/ZLib)** (with / without speedups).