# Run / Debug a Django application's UnitTests from the mouse right click context menu in PyCharm Community Edition?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pycharm

I must emphasize on *PyCharm **Community** Edition* which does **not have any *Django* integration** (*v**2016.3.2*** at question time).

I've *Google*d my problem and (surprisingly,) I did not get any answers, (of course I don't exclude the possibility that there might be some, be but I just missed them).

The question is simple: in *PyCharm*, one can Run (Debug) an Unit Test (*TestCase* or one of its methods) with a simple mouse right click (from the context menu) just as in the image below:

[image: Run Django Unit Test at RClick]

Unfortunately, that yields an exception:

> ```py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Install\PyCharm Community Edition\2016.3.2\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py", line 254, in <module>
>         main()
>     File "C:\Install\PyCharm Community Edition\2016.3.2\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py", line 232, in main
>         module = loadSource(a[0])
>     File "C:\Install\PyCharm Community Edition\2016.3.2\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py", line 65, in loadSource
>         module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fileName)
>     File "E:\Work\Dev\Django\Tutorials\proj0\src\polls\tests.py", line 7, in <module>
>         from polls.models import Question
>     File "E:\Work\Dev\Django\Tutorials\proj0\src\polls\models.py", line 9, in <module>
>         class Question(models.Model):
>     File "E:\Work\Dev\Django\Tutorials\proj0\src\polls\models.py", line 10, in Question
>         question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
>     File "E:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py2713x64-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1043, in __init__
>         super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "E:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py2713x64-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
>         self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
>     File "E:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py2713x64-django\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
>         self._setup(name)
>     File "E:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py2713x64-django\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
>         % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
>     django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
> ```

**Note**: I only added the question to provide an answer that might be useful to someone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Background info

---

- I am only working with *Django* for ~3 months
- Regarding *PyCharm*, I worked with it for some years, but only as an IDE (like *PyCharm for dummies*), so I didn't get into its advanced stuff

Considering the above, some (or all) parts of the solution might seem cumbersome / stupid for some advanced users, so please bear with me. I will incorporate any possible comment that adds value into the solution.

Back to the question: I did my tests / research on a project that consists of *Django Tutorial* ([[DjangoProject]: Writing your first Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01)) + some parts from *Django Rest Framework Tutorial* ([[DRF]: Quickstart](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart)). As an example, I'm going to attempt running *polls/tests.py*: `QuestionViewTests.test_index_view_with_no_questions()`

As a note, **setting *DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE*** as the exception instructs, **triggers another one**, and so on ...

2. Creating a *Python* configuration

---

Although this is not an answer to the question (it's only remotely related), I'm posting it anyway (I'm sure that many people already did it):

- Click on the menu *Run -> Edit Configurations...*
- On the *Run/Debug Configurations* dialog:
- Add a new configuration having the type: **Python**
- Set the *Working directory* to the root path of your project (for me it is "*E:\Work\Dev\Django\Tutorials\proj0\src*"). By default, this will also add the path in the *Python*'s modules search paths
- Set the *Script* to your *Django* project startup script (*manage.py*)
- Set the *Script parameters* to the test parameters (`test QuestionViewTests.test_index_view_with_no_questions`)
- Give your configuration a name (optional) and click *OK*. Now, you will be able to run this test

Of course, having to do this for every test case (and their methods) is not the way to go (it is truly annoying), so this approach is not scalable.

3. Adjusting *PyCharm* to do what we want

---

Just to be noted that I don't see this as a true solution, it's more like a (lame) workaround (*gainarie*), and it's also intrusive.

Let's start by looking what happens when we *RClick* on a *test* (I'm going to use this term in general - it might mean Test Case or method or whole test file, unless specified otherwise). For me, it is running the following command:

> ```
> "E:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py2713x64-django\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Install\PyCharm Community Edition\2016.3.2\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py" E:\Work\Dev\Django\Tutorials\proj0\src\polls\tests.py::QuestionViewTests::test_index_view_with_no_questions true
> ```

As you can see, it's launching "*C:\Install\PyCharm Community Edition\2016.3.2\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py*" (I'm going to refer to it as *utrunner*) with a bunch of arguments (the 1<sup>st</sup> matters to us, since it's the test specification). *utrunner* uses a test run framework which does not care about *Django* (actually there is some *Django* handling code, but that's not helping us).

A few words on *PyCharm*`s *Run/Debug configurations*:

- When *RClick*-ing on a *test*, *PyCharm* automatically creates a new *Run configuration* (that you will be able to save), just like you would from the *Run/Debug Configurations* dialog. An **important** thing to note is the configuration type which is **Python tests/Unittests** (which automatically fires *utrunner*)
- When creating a *Run configuration* in general, *PyCharm* "copies" the settings from that configuration type **Defaults** (can be viewed in the *Run/Debug Configurations* dialog), into the new configuration, and fills the others with specific data. One important thing about **Default configurations** is that they are **project based**: they reside in the *.idea* folder (*workspace.xml*) of the project, so modifying them would not impact other projects (as I first feared)

With the above in mind, let's proceed:

*First thing* you need to do is: from the *Run/Debug Configurations* dialog (menu: *Run -> Edit Configurations...*), edit the **Defaults/Python tests/Unittests** settings:

- Set the *Working directory* just like in the previous approach
- In the *Environment variables* add a new one named *DJANGO_TEST_MODE_GAINARIE* and set it to any string (other than empty/*null*)

*Second thing* and the trickier one (also involving intrusion): patching *utrunner*.

*utrunner.patch*:

```
--- utrunner.py.orig    2016-12-28 19:06:22.000000000 +0200
+++ utrunner.py 2017-03-23 15:20:13.643084400 +0200
@@ -113,7 +113,74 @@
   except:
     pass

-if __name__ == "__main__":
+
+def fileToMod(filePath, basePath):
+  if os.path.exists(filePath) and filePath.startswith(basePath):
+    modList = filePath[len(basePath):].split(os.path.sep)
+    mods = ".".join([os.path.splitext(item)[0] for item in modList if item])
+    return mods
+  else:
+    return None
+
+
+def utrunnerArgToDjangoTest(arg, basePath):
+  if arg.strip() and not arg.startswith("--"):
+    testData = arg.split("::")
+    mods = fileToMod(testData[0], basePath)
+    if mods:
+      testData[0] = mods
+      return ".".join(testData)
+    else:
+      return None
+  else:
+    return None
+
+
+def flushBuffers():
+  sys.stdout.write(os.linesep)
+  sys.stdout.flush()
+  sys.stderr.write(os.linesep)
+  sys.stderr.flush()
+
+
+def runModAsMain(argv, codeGlobals):
+  with open(argv[0]) as f:
+    codeStr = f.read()
+  sys.argv = argv
+  code = compile(codeStr, os.path.basename(argv[0]), "exec")
+  codeGlobals.update({
+    "__name__": "__main__",
+    "__file__": argv[0]
+    })
+  exec(code, codeGlobals)
+
+
+def djangoMain():
+  djangoTests = list()
+  basePath = os.getcwd()
+  for arg in sys.argv[1: -1]:
+    djangoTest = utrunnerArgToDjangoTest(arg, basePath)
+    if djangoTest:
+      djangoTests.append(djangoTest)
+  if not djangoTests:
+    debug("/ [DJANGO MODE] Invalid arguments: " + sys.argv[1: -1])
+  startupTestArgs = [item for item in os.getenv("DJANGO_STARTUP_TEST_ARGS", "").split(" ") if item]
+  startupFullName = os.path.join(basePath, os.getenv("DJANGO_STARTUP_NAME", "manage.py"))
+  if not os.path.isfile(startupFullName):
+    debug("/ [DJANGO MODE] Invalid startup file: " + startupFullName)
+    return
+  djangoStartupArgs = [startupFullName, "test"]
+  djangoStartupArgs.extend(startupTestArgs)
+  djangoStartupArgs.extend(djangoTests)
+  additionalGlobalsStr = os.getenv("DJANGO_STARTUP_ADDITIONAL_GLOBALS", "{}")
+  import ast
+  additionalGlobals = ast.literal_eval(additionalGlobalsStr)
+  flushBuffers()
+  runModAsMain(djangoStartupArgs, additionalGlobals)
+  flushBuffers()
+
+
+def main():
   arg = sys.argv[-1]
   if arg == "true":
     import unittest
@@ -186,3 +253,10 @@

   debug("/ Loaded " + str(all.countTestCases()) + " tests")
   TeamcityTestRunner().run(all, **options)
+
+
+if __name__ == "__main__":
+  if os.getenv("DJANGO_TEST_MODE_GAINARIE"):
+    djangoMain()
+  else:
+    main()
```

The above is a *diff* ([[man7]: DIFF(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html)) (or a *patch* - the names can be used conjunctively - I prefer (and will use) *patch*): it shows the differences between *utrunner.py.orig* (the original file - that I saved before starting modifying, you don't need to do it) and *utrunner.py* (the current version containing the changes). The command that I used is `diff --binary -uN utrunner.py.orig utrunner.py` (obviously, in *utrunner*'s folder). As a personal remark, *patch* is the preferred form of altering 3<sup>rd</sup> party source code (to keep changes under control, and separate).

What the code in the *patch* does (it's probably harder to follow than plain *Python* code):

- Everything under the *main* block (`if __name__ == "__main__":` or the current behavior) has been moved into a function called *main* (to keep it separate and avoid altering it by mistake)
- The *main* block was modified, so that if the env var *DJANGO_TEST_MODE_GAINARIE* is defined (and not empty), it will follow the new implementation (*djangoMain* function), otherwise it will act *normally*. The new implementation:

  - *fileToMod* subtracts *basePath* from *filePath* and converts the difference into *Python* package style. Ex: `fileToMod("E:\Work\Dev\Django\Tutorials\proj0\src\polls\tests.py", "E:\Work\Dev\Django\Tutorials\proj0\src")`, will return `polls.tests`
  - *utrunnerArgToDjangoTest*: uses the previous function and then adds the class name (*QuestionViewTests*) and (optionally) the method name (*test_index_view_with_no_questions*), so at the end it converts the test specification from *utrunner* format (`E:\Work\Dev\Django\Tutorials\proj0\src\polls\tests.py::QuestionViewTests::test_index_view_with_no_questions`) to *manage.py* format (`polls.tests.QuestionViewTests.test_index_view_with_no_questions`)
  - *flushBuffers*: writes an *eoln* char and flushes the *stdout* and *stderr* buffers (this is needed because I noticed that sometimes the outputs from *PyCharm* and *Django* are interleaved, and the final result is messed up)
  - *runModAsMain*: typically, all the relevant *manage.py* code is under `if __name__ == "__main__":`. This function "tricks" *Python* making it believe that *manage.py* was run as its 1<sup>st</sup> argument

**Patching *utrunner***:

- I did these modifications on my own (I didn't search for versions having *Django* integration and inspire from there)
- *utrunner* is part of *PyCharm*. It's obvious why *JetBrains* guys didn't include **any *Django* integration in the *Community Edition*: to make people buy the *Professional Edition***. This kinda steps on their toes. I'm not aware of the legal implications of modifying *utrunner*, but anyway if you patch it, **you're doing it on your own responsibility and risk**
- Coding style: it sucks (at least from naming / indenting *PoV*), but it's consistent with the rest of the file (the only case when coding style should be allowed to suck). [[Python]: PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) contains the coding style guidelines for *Python*
- The patch is applied on the original file (*utrunner.py*), with the following properties (still valid for *v**2019.2.3*** (last checked: ***20190930***)):

  - size: *5865*
  - sha256sum: *db98d1043125ce2af9a9c49a1f933969678470bd863f791c2460fe090c2948a0*
- Applying the *patch*:

  - *utrunner* is located in "*${PYCHARM_INSTALL_DIR}/helpers/pycharm*"
  - Typically, *${PYCHARM_INSTALL_DIR}* points to:

    - *Nix*: */usr/lib/pycharm-community*
    - *Win*: "*C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.3*" (adapt to your version number)
  - Save the *patch* content (in a file called e.g. *utrunner.patch*, let's assume it's under */tmp*)
  - *Nix* - things are easy, just (***cd*** to *utrunner*'s folder and) run `patch -i /tmp/utrunner.patch`. [[man7]: PATCH(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/patch.1.html) is an utility that is installed by default (part of *patch* dpkg in *Ubtu*). Note that since *utrunner.py* is owned by *root*, for this step you would need **sudo**
  - *Win* - similar steps to be followed, but things are trickier since there's no native *patch* utility. However, there are workarounds:

    - Use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com). As in *Nix* (*Lnx*) case, *patch* utility is available, but **it doesn't get installed by default**. The *patch* pkg must be **explicitly** installed from *Cygwin setup*. I tried this and **it works**
    - There are alternatives (I didn't try them):

      - [[SourceForge.GnuWin32]: Patch for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm)
      - In theory, [[RedBean]: svn patch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.patch.html)(any client) should be able to apply a *patch*, but I'm not sure if the file should be part of a *working copy*.
      - Applying the *patch* manually (a less desired option :) )
    - As in *Nix*'s case, patching the file would (most likely) have to be done by one of the *Administrators*. Also, watch out for file paths, make sure to *(dbl)quote* them if they contain spaces
  - Reverting the *patch*:

    - Backups are not harmful (except from the free disk space's *PoV*, or when they start to pile up, managing them becomes a pain). There's no need for them in our case. In order to revert the changes, just run the command on the modified file: `patch -Ri /tmp/utrunner.patch`, and it will switch it back to its original content (it will also create an *utrunner.py.orig* file with the modified content; it will actually switch the *.py* and *.py.orig* files). 
      Nevertheless **always back 3<sup>rd</sup>-party files up before modifying them** (especially if they're being tracked by some tools / installers), so that if something goes wrong while modifying them, there's always a way to restore the original state
  - Although not the case here, but if the changes are in another form, like the file with the *patch* applied (e.g. on [GitHub](https://github.com)), you can obviously get the entire file (if there are many files, tracking all of them down could become a pain) and overwrite yours. But again, **back it (them) up first**!

**Couple of words about this approach**:

- The code can handle (optional) env vars (other than *DJANGO_TEST_MODE_GAINARIE* - which is mandatory):

  - *DJANGO_STARTUP_NAME*: in case that *manage.py* has other name (for whatever reason?), or is located in another folder than the *Working directory*. An **important** thing here: when specifying file paths, use the platform specific path separator: *slash* (***/***) for *Nix*,  *bkslash* (***\***) for *Win*
  - *DJANGO_STARTUP_TEST_ARGS*: additional arguments that `manage.py test` accepts (run `manage.py test --help` to get the whole list). Here, I have to insist on ***-k*** / ***--keepdb*** which preserves the test database (*test_${REGULAR_DB_NAME}* by default or set in *settings* under the *TEST* dictionary) between runs. When running a single test, creating the *DB* (and applying all the migrations) and destroying it can be be time consuming (and very annoying as well). This flag ensures that the *DB* is not deleted at the end and will be reused at the next test run
  - *DJANGO_STARTUP_ADDITIONAL_GLOBALS*: this must have the string representation of a *Python dict*. Any values that for some reason are required by *manage.py* to be present in the `globals()` dictionary, should be placed here
- When modifying a *Default configuration*, all previously created configurations that inherit it, **won't be updated**, so they have to be manually **removed** (and will be automatically recreated by new *RClick*s on their *tests*)

*RClick* on the same test (after deleting its previous configuration :d), and ***voilà***:

> ```
> E:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py2713x64-django\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Install\PyCharm Community Edition\2016.3.2\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py" E:\Work\Dev\Django\Tutorials\proj0\src\polls\tests.py::QuestionViewTests::test_index_view_with_no_questions true
> Testing started at 01:38 ...
>
>
> Using existing test database for alias 'default'...
> .
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> Ran 1 test in 0.390s
>
> OK
>
> Preserving test database for alias 'default'...
>
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

Debugging also works (breakpoints, and so on ...).

**Caveats** (so far I identified 2 of them):

- This is benign, it's only an *UI* issue: *utrunner* (most likely) has some initialization that *PyCharm* expects to take place, which obviously doesn't in our case. So, even if the test ended successfully, from *PyCharm*'s *PoV* they didn't and therefore the *Output* window will contain a warning: "*Test framework quit unexpectedly*"
- This is a nasty one, and I wasn't able to get to the bottom of it (yet). Apparently, in *utrunner* any `input`(`raw_input`) call is not handled very well; the prompt text: "*Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_tut-proj0', or 'no' to cancel:*" (which appears if the previous test run crashed, and its *DB* was not destroyed at the end) is not being displayed and the program freezes (this doesn't happen outside *utrunner*), without letting the user to input text (maybe there are threads in the mix?). The only way to recover is stopping the test run, deleting the *DB* and running the test again. Again, I have to promote the `manage.py test -k` flag which will get around this problem

I've worked/tested on the following **environments**:

- *Nix* (*Lnx*):

  - *Ubtu 16.04 x64*
  - *PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.3*
  - *Python 3.4.4* (*VEnv*)
  - *Django 1.9.5*
- *Win*:

  - *W10 x64*
  - *PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2*
  - *Python 2.7.13* (*VEnv*)
  - *Django 1.10.6*

**Notes**:

- I will continue investigating the current issues (at least the 2<sup>nd</sup> one)
- A **clean** solution would be to override somehow in *PyCharm* the Unit Test running default settings (what I did from code), but I couldn't find any config files (probably it's in the *PyCharm* jars?)
- I noticed a lot of files/folders that are specific to *Django* in the *helpers* (*utrunner*'s parent) folder, maybe those can be used too, will have to check

As I stated at the beginning, any suggestion is more than welcome!

***@EDIT0***:

- As I replied to @Udi's comment, this is an alternative for people who can't afford (or companies that aren't willing) to pay the *PyCharm Professional Edition* license fee (on a quick browse it looks like it's *~100$-200$* / year for each instance)

Comment: Or: buy pycharm professional edition, which has many great features for django.

Comment: That's true (or at least so I saw on screenshots), but this is an alternative for some that might not afford the 100$-200$ per year (or some companies simply refuse to pay those amounts).

Comment: The first issue can be fixed by using test runner `teamcity.django.TeamcityDjangoRunner` from [teamcity-messages](https://pypi.org/project/teamcity-messages/).

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/AndreyMZ/jb_django_test_runner/blob/master/README.md.

Pros:

1. It works with PyCharm 2019.3.2.
2. Output windows shows test results instead of error "Test framework quit unexpectedly".