# virtualenv not creating activat.bat windows

Tags: python, windows

I am relatively new to python packages, and I am trying to create a virtual environment for the first time, but it is not creating an activate.bat file like it says it should in [pymote.readthedocs.io](http://pymote.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/windows_virtualenv.html). I am on a Windows 7 machine, using Python 2.7, and my only other library is pygame if any of that is useful. I have also tried using other websites, like [tylerbutler.com](http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/), and

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far, and where did you encounter problems. Check [\[SO\]: How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [\[SO\]: mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more asking related details. More details are required (e.g. commands run, their results, and so on...). Maybe [\[SO\]: Create Windows Python virtualenv with a specific version of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165220/create-windows-python-virtualenv-with-a-specific-version-of-python) could help.

Comment: I have stated what I tried so far, those two websites, and looking on sites I can't find anything that I too different (too many websites to list), I encountered problems because there is no activate.bat. the commands that I ran are listed in the links. their result, like I stated, was a perfectly normal folder, just there aren't any batch files in the scripts folder, so there is no activate.bat, what was I missing?