# How to install a specific version of python in the virtual enivironment in windows?

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I have python 3.6.6 and I can create a virtual environment with this version using `virtulaenv .`.I have installed python in drive(C) C:\python36 where the OS is installed.How can I install a specific version like python 2.7.16 in the virtual environment.Do I have to install python 2.7.16 manualy or **will it download itself**?I saw some answers for linux but couldn't get it.I tried

> PS C:\Users\Husni\Desktop\dev> virtualenv -p C:/python2.7.16 **.**
>
> The path C:/python2.7.16 (from --python=C:/python2.7.16) does not
>   exist

Then I tried

> PS C:\Users\Husni\Desktop\dev> virtualenv -p python36 **.**
>
> The path python36 (from --python=python36) does not exist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using VirtualEnv with multiple Python versions on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793650/using-virtualenv-with-multiple-python-versions-on-windows) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165220/create-windows-python-virtualenv-with-a-specific-version-of-python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293436/how-to-specify-python-version-used-to-create-virtual-environment

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Answer (score 0):

you can't. install python 2 and virtualenv for it and run like "py -2 -m virtualenv venv"

Comment: How can I install virtualenv to python2?Do I have to add python2 to the PATH?

Comment: Thank you.I tried `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install virtualenv` and it worked!