# How to create libjson.lib using makefile on windows?

Tags: windows, makefile, compiler-errors, mingw, libjson

I downloaded C++ libJSON from this link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/libjson/
How can I create a library using the code they have provided?

I installed MinGW, added it to the path in the environment variable and did cd to the directory, where I have the makefile and tried using mingw32-make.exe.
BUT I get this error:

[image]

I understand that I need to add arguments, but I don't know what to add..
Could you please assist? 
thanks!

Comment: `mingw32-make` is the only command you ran? Nothing else before (including env vars set)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on *v**7.6.1*** (latest at this point). Downloaded it from [[SourceForge]: ninja9578/libjson - libjson_7.6.1.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libjson/files/libjson_7.6.1.zip).

At the beginning, I thought it was a half hour problem (minor changes in the  *makefile*, since *Win*'s *mkdir* creates nested dirs by default, and doesn't accept a *-p* argument).

To make things clear, I tried running *MinGW*'s *mingw32-make* from *Win*'s *cmd* window (no additional wrappers involved).

So, I started inserting (in the  *makefile*) conditional commands (based on *OS*), but it was not enough. The changes needed by the original *makefile* to accommodate this scenario, seemed simply too large (making the file harder to understand) compared to the gain: work on an environment that too few people care about, so the logical solution was to create a separate *makefile* (called it ***Makefile.mak***)

Nevertheless, the official doc (*"${LIBJSON_SRC_DIR}/Documentation.pdf"*) states that:

> MinGW (Windows) - **Supported**, partially tested

I didn't get through the whole *.pdf* to see what are the required conditions for that to happen, but (besides that it doesn't work - hence the existence of this question) looking at the *makefile*, there are some things that don't look right:

- Shell (*Nix* (*sh*, *bash*, ...) *vs.* *Win* (*batch* (*cmd*), *PS*, *VBS*, ...)) commands (**qualified as usable** in a *GNU* *makefile*) difference (`rm -f` *vs.* `del /Q /S`)
- The way *makefile* commands are carried (*CreateProcess* for each of them: including **`cd`** - which **doesn't change** the environment (*cwd*), leading to the next command failure), also the command separator (***;***), doesn't work as expected
- *FS* path separators (***/*** *vs.* ***\***) handled by the above commands

I "converted" the *makefile*, considering that current *Nix* (*Lnx*) behavior should be preserved on *Win*, and I also found some (syntax) errors (so, apparently the ***Nix* version was not working either** - well the library was built, but that's about it). Fixed the errors, and then wanted to post the answer on the **official site** (so that anyone who used to follow it, should be aware of the changes).

Briefly looked, and noticed that last action is from *180622* (there are more, around that date). But when took a closer look, it seems that the last actual work was done ***5* years ago** (*2013*), so I'm not sure if it's maintained (also quick browsed [GitHub](https://github.com), but didn't find it).

Anyway, I contacted the author, as I don't have permissions to open tickets (submit patches), but I got no reply, so I started a thread: [[SourceForge]: ninja9578/libjson - Request for permissions to submit a patch](https://sourceforge.net/p/libjson/discussion/1119661/thread/c8ab4cd7/?limit=25#aebd). I will submit the patch (provided that the permissions will be granted to me).

#### Long story short

Anyway, here's the *Win* *makefile* (mostly copied from original one):

*Makefile.mak*:

```make
###############################################################################
#                                                       
#  Copyright 2010 Jonathan Wallace. All rights reserved.         
#
#  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
#  modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
#
#      1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
#         notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
#
#      2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
#         notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
#         documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
#
#  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY JONATHAN WALLACE ``AS IS'' AND ANY 
#  EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE 
#  IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR 
#  PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL JONATHAN WALLACE OR
#  CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, 
#  EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED 
#  TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, 
#  DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON
#  ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR 
#  TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF 
#  THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH 
#  DAMAGE.
#
#  The views and conclusions contained in the software and documentation are
#  those of the authors and should not be interpreted as representing official
#  policies, either expressed or implied, of Jonathan Wallace....
#
#
#  Author Bernhard Fluehmann
#
#  bernhard.fluehmann@patton-inalp.com
#
#
#  Adapted for Windows (MinGW) by Cristi Fati (fati_utcluj@yahoo.com)
#
#
#  TARGETS
#    all
#      Builds either a shared or a static library, depending of the value
#      of the SHARED variable.
#      Default: static
#
#    banner
#      Displays the library version and the target
#
#    install
#      Installs either the shared of the static library, depending of the value
#      of the SHARED variable. Installs the header files as well.
#      Builds the library before installing if it does not exist already.
#      Ececutes ldconfig in case of the shared library.
#      Default locations:
#        library: $(exec_prefix)/$(libdir) => /usr/lib
#        headers:   $(prefix)/$(includedir) => /usr/include
#
#    install_headers
#      Installs the header files.
#      Default location: $(prefix)/$(includedir) => /usr/include
#
#    clean
#      Removes the shared or the static library, depending of the value
#      of the SHARED variable, from this folder and all the folders and objects
#      which were created to build it.
#
#    uninstall
#      Removes the shared or the static library, depending of the value
#      of the SHARED variable from the system. In case of the shared library,
#      removes the symbolic links as well and executes ldconfig.
#
#    uninstall_headers
#      Remove the headers from the system.
#
#  Variables
#    prefix
#      The general installation root directory. Default: /usr
#
#    exec_prefix
#      The installation root directory to place executables and libraries.
#      Default: prefix
#
#    libdir
#      The directory where the libraries are installed, as a subdirectory of
#      exec_prefix. Default: lib
#
#    includedir
#      The directory where the header files are installed, as a subdirectory of
#      prefix. Default: include
#
#    srcdir
#      The directory where the object source files are located.
#      Default: _internal/Source
#
#    CXX
#      The compiler to be used. Default: c++
#
#    CXXFLAGS
#      The compiler flags used to compile the object files.
#      Default:
#        cxxflags_default for default
#        cxxflags_small   for BUILD_TYPE=small
#        cxxflags_debug   for BUILD_TYPE=debug
#
#    AR
#      The archiver to be used. Default: ar
#
#    PIC
#      The PIC to be used. Default: PIC
#
#    BUILD_TYPE
#      Used to select a specific set of predefined configuration parameters.
#      Default:  undefined: The default settings are used
#      Options:
#        small
#        debug
#
#    SHARED
#      Used to select if the library is a shared or a dynamic one
#      Default: undefined: static
#      Options:
#        0:         static
#        1:         shared
#
#
#

# Shell (cmd) commands
movefile = move /Y
copyfile = copy /Y
removefile = del /Q /S
makedirs = -mkdir
copydir = xcopy /B /E /H /K /Y
removedir = -rmdir /Q /S
makelink = mklink


# JSON source files to build
objects = internalJSONNode.o JSONAllocator.o JSONChildren.o \
          JSONDebug.o JSONIterators.o JSONMemory.o JSONNode.o \
          JSONNode_Mutex.o JSONPreparse.o JSONStream.o JSONValidator.o \
          JSONWorker.o JSONWriter.o libjson.o

# Defaults
cxxflags_default = -O3 -ffast-math -fexpensive-optimizations -DNDEBUG
cxxflags_small = -Os -ffast-math -DJSON_LESS_MEMORY -DNDEBUG
cxxflags_debug = -g -DJSON_SAFE -DJSON_DEBUG
cxxflags_shared = -f$(PIC)
libname = libjson
libname_hdr := $(libname)
libname_debug = $(libname)_dbg
suffix_shared = so
suffix_static = a
major_version = 7
minor_version = 6.1
objdir = Objects


# Variables
prefix ?= ../install_libjson
exec_prefix ?= $(prefix)
libdir ?= lib
includedir ?= include
intdir ?= _internal
srcdir ?= $(intdir)/Source
CXX ?= c++
AR ?= ar
PIC ?= PIC
BUILD_TYPE ?= "default"
SHARED ?= "1"


# Internal Variables
inst_path = $(exec_prefix)/$(libdir)
include_path = $(prefix)/$(includedir)

install_include_lib_dir = $(include_path)/$(libname_hdr)
install_include_lib_src_dir = $(install_include_lib_dir)/$(srcdir)

# Usage check
ifdef CXXFLAGS
ifdef BUILD_TYPE
    $(error CXXFLAGS and BUILD_TYPE are mutually exclusive)
endif
endif

# BUILD_TYPE specific settings
ifeq ($(BUILD_TYPE),small)
    CXXFLAGS = $(cxxflags_small)
else ifeq ($(BUILD_TYPE),debug)
    CXXFLAGS = $(cxxflags_debug)
    libname := $(libname_debug)
else
    CXXFLAGS ?= $(cxxflags_default)
endif

# SHARED specific settings
ifeq ($(SHARED),1)
    libname_shared = $(libname).$(suffix_shared)
    libname_shared_major_version = $(libname_shared).$(major_version)
    lib_target = $(libname_shared_major_version).$(minor_version)
    objdir := $(objdir)_shared
    CXXFLAGS := $(CXXFLAGS) $(cxxflags_shared)
else
    lib_target = $(libname).$(suffix_static)
    objdir := $(objdir)_static
endif

# Win styple paths - to be used by shell commands
objdir_win = $(subst /,\,$(objdir))
inst_path_win = $(subst /,\,$(inst_path))
intdir_win = $(subst /,\,$(intdir))
srcdir_win = $(subst /,\,$(srcdir))
install_include_lib_dir_win = $(subst /,\,$(install_include_lib_dir))
install_include_lib_src_dir_win = $(subst /,\,$(install_include_lib_src_dir))


# Phony targets
.PHONY: all banner installdirs install install_headers clean uninstall uninstall_headers

# Targets
all: $(lib_target)
    @echo "============================================================"
    @echo "Done"
    @echo "============================================================"

banner:
    @echo "============================================================"
    @echo "libjson version: "$(major_version).$(minor_version) "target: "$(target) "OS: "Windows
    @echo "============================================================"

installdirs: banner
    $(makedirs) $(objdir_win)

# Libraries
ifeq ($(SHARED),1)
$(lib_target): banner installdirs $(addprefix $(objdir)/, $(objects))
    @echo "Link "
    cd $(objdir_win) && \
    $(CXX) -shared -Wl,-soname,$(libname_shared_major_version) -o $@ $(objects) && \
    $(movefile) $@ ..
    @echo "Link: Done"
else
$(lib_target): banner installdirs $(addprefix $(objdir)/, $(objects))
    @echo "Archive"
    cd $(objdir_win) && \
    $(AR) -cvq $@ $(objects) && \
    $(movefile) $@ ..
    @echo "Archive: Done"
endif

# Compile object files
$(objdir)/%.o: $(srcdir)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $< -o $@ -c $(CXXFLAGS)

ifeq ($(SHARED),1)
install: banner install_headers $(lib_target)
    @echo "Install shared library"
    $(makedirs) $(inst_path_win)
    $(copyfile) $(lib_target) $(inst_path_win)
    cd $(inst_path_win) && \
    $(removefile) $(libname_shared_major_version) && $(makelink) $(libname_shared_major_version) $(lib_target) && \
    $(removefile) $(libname_shared) && $(makelink) $(libname_shared) $(libname_shared_major_version)
    @echo ldconfig
    @echo "Install shared library: Done."
else
install: banner install_headers $(lib_target)
    @echo "Install static library"
    $(makedirs) $(inst_path_win)
    $(copyfile) .\$(lib_target) $(inst_path_win)
    @echo "Install static library: Done."
endif

install_headers: banner
    @echo "Install header files"
    $(makedirs) $(install_include_lib_src_dir_win)\JSONDefs
    $(makedirs) $(install_include_lib_src_dir_win)\Dependencies
    $(copyfile) .\*.h $(install_include_lib_dir_win)
    -$(removefile) $(install_include_lib_dir_win)\.*.h
    $(copyfile) .\$(srcdir_win)\*.h $(install_include_lib_src_dir_win)
    -$(removefile) $(install_include_lib_src_dir_win)\.*.h
    $(copydir) .\$(srcdir_win)\JSONDefs $(install_include_lib_src_dir_win)\JSONDefs
    $(copydir) $(intdir_win)\Dependencies $(install_include_lib_src_dir_win)\Dependencies
    @echo "Install header files: Done."

clean: banner
    @echo "Clean library and object folder"
    $(removedir) $(objdir_win)
    -$(removefile) $(lib_target)
    @echo "Clean library and object folder: Done"

ifeq ($(SHARED),1)
uninstall: banner uninstall_headers
    @echo "Uninstall shared library"
    -$(removefile) $(inst_path_win)\$(libname)*
    @echo ldconfig
    @echo "Uninstall shared library: Done"
else
uninstall: banner uninstall_headers
    @echo "Uninstall static library"
    -$(removefile) $(inst_path_win)\$(lib_target)
    @echo "Uninstall static library: Done"
endif

uninstall_headers: banner
    @echo "Uninstall header files"
    $(removedir) $(install_include_lib_dir_win)
    @echo "Uninstall header files: Done"

test:
    $(CXX) _internal/TestSuite/main.cpp  _internal/TestSuite/TestAssign.cpp  _internal/TestSuite/TestChildren.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite/TestComments.cpp  _internal/TestSuite/TestConverters.cpp  _internal/TestSuite/TestCtors.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite/TestEquality.cpp  _internal/TestSuite/TestFunctions.cpp  _internal/TestSuite/TestInequality.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite/TestInspectors.cpp  _internal/TestSuite/TestIterators.cpp  _internal/TestSuite/TestMutex.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite/TestNamespace.cpp  _internal/TestSuite/TestRefCounting.cpp _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite/TestWriter.cpp  _internal/TestSuite/TestString.cpp  _internal/TestSuite/UnitTest.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite/TestValidator.cpp  _internal/TestSuite/TestStreams.cpp  _internal/TestSuite/TestBinary.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite/RunTestSuite2.cpp  _internal/TestSuite/TestSharedString.cpp \
    _internal/Source/internalJSONNode.cpp  _internal/Source/JSONPreparse.cpp  _internal/Source/JSONChildren.cpp \
    _internal/Source/JSONDebug.cpp  _internal/Source/JSONIterators.cpp  _internal/Source/JSONMemory.cpp \
    _internal/Source/JSONNode_Mutex.cpp  _internal/Source/JSONNode.cpp  _internal/Source/JSONWorker.cpp \
    _internal/Source/JSONWriter.cpp  _internal/Source/libjson.cpp  _internal/Source/JSONValidator.cpp \
    _internal/Source/JSONStream.cpp  _internal/Source/JSONAllocator.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/JSON_Base64/json_decode64.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/JSON_Base64/json_encode64.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/JSONDebug/JSON_ASSERT_SAFE.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/JSONDebug/JSON_ASSERT.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/JSONDebug/JSON_FAIL_SAFE.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/JSONDebug/JSON_FAIL.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/JSONGlobals/jsonSingleton.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidArray.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidMember.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidNamedObject.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidNumber.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidObject.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidPartialRoot.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidRoot.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidString.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/securityTest.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/NumberToString/_areFloatsEqual.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/NumberToString/_atof.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/NumberToString/_ftoa.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/NumberToString/_itoa.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/NumberToString/_uitoa.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/NumberToString/getLenSize.cpp \
    _internal/TestSuite2/NumberToString/isNumeric.cpp \
    $(CXXFLAGS) -o ./testapp
    ./testapp
```

Steps:

- Unpack the sources archive (I have them in a dir called *libjson*)
- Copy *Makefile.mak* in that dir
- From inside the dir, call (in a ***cmd*** window) *mingw32-make* against this file (`mingw32-make -f Makefile.mak`)

  - In order for everything to work normally, *mingw32-make*'s dir must be in *%PATH%* (which you already know)
  - If you want the dynamic version (*.so* - which is actually a *.dll*), you must `set SHARED=1` before invoking *mingw32-make*
  - Due to *mklink*, the *install* target won't work on older *Win* versions (e.g. *XP*)

When building the lib, I've encountered a strange thing that you should be aware of. Here are the tool versions / environments that I've worked on:

1. *g++ 5.3.0* on *Win* - part of *MinGW* (installed by *Qt*)
2. *g++ 5.4.0* on *Lnx* (*Ubtu*)
3. *g++ 7.2.0* on *Win* - part of *MinGW* (built by me)
4. *g++ 7.3.0* on *Cygwin*

3 of those worked fine, but for ***#3.***, I got:

> ```
> _internal/Source/JSONWorker.cpp:297:26: error: cast from 'const char*' to 'long int' loses precision [-fpermissive]
>   JSON_ASSERT_SAFE(((long)end - (long)pos) > 4, JSON_TEXT("UTF will go out of bounds"), return JSON_TEXT('\0'););
>                           ^
> ```

I don't know why this happens (probably a *g++* config issue?), but in order to get around it, you should add the ***-fpermissive*** compile flag (as instructed by the error message) to *cxxflags_default* variable in line ***#146***:

```
cxxflags_default = -O3 -ffast-math -fexpensive-optimizations -fpermissive -DNDEBUG
```

This is for the default build, if you choose another variant (*debug*, *small*) you'll have to modify the appropriate variable.

Although it wasn't required in the question, I'm also posting the fixes for the *Nix* part (which are somehow related, since I've discovered them while working on this answer).

*libjson-7.6.1-nix_makefile.patch*:

```diff
--- libjson/makefile.orig   2012-05-30 05:15:42.000000000 +0300
+++ libjson/makefile    2018-08-31 01:09:57.484855300 +0300
@@ -131,7 +131,7 @@
 OS=$(shell uname)

 # Defaults
-ifeq ($(OS), Darwin)
+ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
    cxxflags_default = -fast -ffast-math -fexpensive-optimizations -DNDEBUG
 else
    cxxflags_default = -O3 -ffast-math -fexpensive-optimizations -DNDEBUG
@@ -154,7 +154,8 @@
 exec_prefix     ?= $(prefix)
 libdir          ?= lib
 includedir      ?= include
-srcdir          ?= _internal/Source
+intdir          ?= _internal
+srcdir          ?= $(intdir)/Source
 CXX             ?= c++
 AR              ?= ar
 PIC             ?= PIC
@@ -175,9 +176,9 @@
 endif

 # BUILD_TYPE specific settings
-ifeq ($(BUILD_TYPE), small)
+ifeq ($(BUILD_TYPE),small)
    CXXFLAGS     = $(cxxflags_small)
-else ifeq ($(BUILD_TYPE), debug)
+else ifeq ($(BUILD_TYPE),debug)
    CXXFLAGS     = $(cxxflags_debug)
    libname     := $(libname_debug)
 else
@@ -185,7 +186,7 @@
 endif

 # SHARED specific settings
-ifeq ($(SHARED), 1)
+ifeq ($(SHARED),1)
    libname_shared               = $(libname).$(suffix_shared)
    libname_shared_major_version = $(libname_shared).$(major_version)
    lib_target                   = $(libname_shared_major_version).$(minor_version)
@@ -242,6 +243,7 @@
 ifeq ($(SHARED),1)
 install: banner install_headers $(lib_target)
    @echo "Install shared library"
+   mkdir -p $(inst_path)
    cp -f ./$(lib_target) $(inst_path)
    cd $(inst_path) ; \
    ln -sf $(lib_target) $(libname_shared_major_version) ; \
@@ -253,6 +255,7 @@
 else
 install: banner install_headers $(lib_target)
    @echo "Install static library"
+   mkdir -p $(inst_path)
    cp -f ./$(lib_target) $(inst_path)
    @echo "Install static library: Done."
 endif
@@ -265,8 +268,8 @@
    cp -f ./$(srcdir)/*.h $(include_path)/$(libname_hdr)/$(srcdir)
    cp -r ./$(srcdir)/JSONDefs $(include_path)/$(libname_hdr)/$(srcdir)
    chmod -R a+r $(include_path)/$(libname_hdr)
-   find  $(include_path)/$(libname_hdr) -type d -exec chmod a+x {} \;
-   cp -rv $(srcdir)/Dependencies/ $(include_path)/$(libname_hdr)/$(srcdir)
+   find $(include_path)/$(libname_hdr) -type d -exec chmod a+x {} \;
+   cp -rv $(intdir)/Dependencies/ $(include_path)/$(libname_hdr)/$(srcdir)
    @echo "Install header files: Done."

 clean: banner
@@ -311,28 +314,28 @@
    _internal/Source/JSONNode_Mutex.cpp     _internal/Source/JSONNode.cpp           _internal/Source/JSONWorker.cpp \
    _internal/Source/JSONWriter.cpp         _internal/Source/libjson.cpp            _internal/Source/JSONValidator.cpp \
    _internal/Source/JSONStream.cpp         _internal/Source/JSONAllocator.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/JSON_Base64/json_decode64.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/JSON_Base64/json_encode64.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/JSONDebug/JSON_ASSERT_SAFE.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/JSONDebug/JSON_ASSERT.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/JSONDebug/JSON_FAIL_SAFE.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/JSONDebug/JSON_FAIL.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/JSONGlobals/jsonSingleton.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidArray.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidMember.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidNamedObject.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidNumber.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidObject.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidPartialRoot.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidRoot.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidString.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/securityTest.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/NumberToString/_areFloatsEqual.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/NumberToString/_atof.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/NumberToString/_ftoa.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/NumberToString/_itoa.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/NumberToString/_uitoa.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/NumberToString/getLenSize.cpp \
-   _internal/TestSuite/TestSuite2/NumberToString/isNumeric.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/JSON_Base64/json_decode64.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/JSON_Base64/json_encode64.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/JSONDebug/JSON_ASSERT_SAFE.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/JSONDebug/JSON_ASSERT.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/JSONDebug/JSON_FAIL_SAFE.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/JSONDebug/JSON_FAIL.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/JSONGlobals/jsonSingleton.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidArray.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidMember.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidNamedObject.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidNumber.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidObject.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidPartialRoot.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidRoot.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/isValidString.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/JSONValidator/securityTest.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/NumberToString/_areFloatsEqual.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/NumberToString/_atof.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/NumberToString/_ftoa.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/NumberToString/_itoa.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/NumberToString/_uitoa.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/NumberToString/getLenSize.cpp \
+   _internal/TestSuite2/NumberToString/isNumeric.cpp \
    $(CXXFLAGS) -o ./testapp
    ./testapp
```

The above is a *diff*. See [[SO]: Run/Debug a Django application's UnitTests from the mouse right click context menu in PyCharm Community Edition? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989471/run-debug-a-django-applications-unittests-from-the-mouse-right-click-context-me/42989490#42989490) (**Patching *utrunner*** section) for how to apply patches on *Win* (basically, every line that starts with **one "+"** sign goes in, and every line that starts with **one "-"** sign goes out). I am using *Cygwin*, *btw*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation