# CS50 Finance - NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, cs50

I am getting `500 Internal Server Error` when running flask with the following error message:

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Yesterday my code worked fine and I didn't make any changes. The error message lists python files which were already imported in the distribution code. Maybe something changed in the background?

```
192.168.234.116 - - [10/Jul/2019 11:15:56] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 303, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 291, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/pset8/finance/application.py", line 13, in <module>
    app = Flask(__name__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cs50/flask.py", line 54, in _after
    self.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(self.wsgi_app, x_proto=1)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: Please add code snippets with your questions along with stack-traces

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Even if this doesn't seem to be related to your code, you should post a *mcve* anyway: the minimum parts of *application.py* that when ran, the error becomes visible, otherwise you risk the question being closed for not following the guidelines (even if the question brings up a valid point).

Comment: @CristiFati thank you, I will use your advice.

Answer (score 1):

It's a *CS50* bug (regression).

I've submitted [[GitHub]: cs50/python-cs50 - Added the 1st (required) argument (self) to flask.Flask's initializer](https://github.com/cs50/python-cs50/pull/81), which was closed (because it was incomplete - as I was too rushed when submitting it, and missed one spot), and **[[GitHub]: Fix missing self arguments in Flask __init__ replacement](https://github.com/cs50/python-cs50/pull/82)** was created and **merged**. Not sure though when will it be available on the market ([PyPI](https://pypi.org), so you can simply `pip install` it), but you could download the sources from *GitHub* and overwrite yours.

As an alternative, you could download the patch, and apply the changes locally. Check [[SO]: Run/Debug a Django application's UnitTests from the mouse right click context menu in PyCharm Community Edition? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989471/run-debug-a-django-applications-unittests-from-the-mouse-right-click-context-me/42989490#42989490) (**Patching *utrunner*** section) for how to apply patches (basically, every line that starts with **one "+"** sign goes in, and every line that starts with **one "-"** sign goes out). 
Or (given the fact that the change is more than trivial), you could:

1. Open the *flask.py* file (in your case: "*/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cs50/flask.py*") in a text editor
2. Go to line ***#54*** (in your case, in mine it's 52)
3. Replace the current content (do **not** alter leading *SPACE*s):

   - For the current line (`def _after(*args, **kwargs):`) by: `def _after(self, *args, **kwargs):`
   - For the next one (`_before(*args, **kwargs)`) by: `_before(self, *args, **kwargs)`

***@EDIT0***:

As @kaczifant already experienced, **the fix is already available for download**: `pip3 install cs50 --upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

The bug was fixed by the CS50 staff.

Select CS50 IDE > Log Out and then log back in at ide.cs50.io. Alternatively, you can run:

```
sudo pip3 install cs50 --upgrade
```