# PyCharm 2019.2 not showing Traceback on Exception

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

Very simple minimal example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Still ok")
    raise Exception("Dummy exception")
    print("End of Program")
```

I get this output when running it in the PyCharm 2019.2 debugger with Python 3.6:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/[...]/pycharm-community-2019.2/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 46850 --file /home/[...]/test_traceback.py
pydev debugger: process 18394 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 192.5728.105)
Still ok
```

At this point the debugger breaks the execution flow but **no Traceback and Exception message is shown** in the Debugger console. If I run the same **in PyCharm 2018.1 it does show these** right when the breakpoint is hit.

When I hit [image: Continue], I get the desired output, but then I can't run code in the debugging context anymore because the process ends:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/[...]/pycharm-community-2019.2/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2060, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/[...]/pycharm-community-2019.2/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2054, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/home/[...]/pycharm-community-2019.2/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1405, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
  File "/home/[...]/pycharm-community-2019.2/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1412, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/[...]/pycharm-community-2019.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/[...]/test_traceback.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise Exception("Dummy exception")
Exception: Dummy exception

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My Breakpoint configuration:

[image: Breakpoint config]

Comment: But... that's how it works? It throws an error, you pause. Traceback in the console is literally the last thing **handler** does. But you pause it **before handler starts**. Your breakpoint is for the exception, not for the inside of the handler (where it prints the traceback) or something like "stop just before you exit".

Comment: This article might be useful: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206588635-Confused-about-exceptions-during-debugging  Short form: examine the `__exception__` variable to see which exception was thrown and its fields.

Comment: @h4z3 The behavior I expect was the one I was used to from older PyCharm versions. To confirm, I just downloaded a fresh PyCharm 2018.1 executed the program and it did stop at the exception, printed the exception message and traceback and still let me debug it in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works on *PyCharm (Community) 2019.**1.4***:

[image: Img0]

Seems like you ran into a (regression) bug:

- [[JetBrains.YouTrack]: No Traceback in Debugger's Console](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37212)

  - [[JetBrains.YouTrack]: No stack trace is printed to the console when debugger breaks on exception](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37805)

which affects ***v2019.2.1***, and is **scheduled to be fixed in *v2019.2.3***.

To **get past this issue**, you'll have to either:

- Wait for *v2019.2.3* (or any other that has the fix) to be released, and switch to that (might want to (periodically) check [[JetBrains.Blog]: Release Announcements](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/category/announcement))
- Revert to a (previous) version which is not affected by the bug (as I already mentioned: *2019.1.4*)

As a note: when running into this kinds of situations, in the (unlikely) case that the problem is not yet known, one could take matters into their own hands, do some debugging, and fix the problem (maybe submit a patch with the fix to *JetBrains*). Check [[SO]: Run / Debug a Django application's UnitTests from the mouse right click context menu in PyCharm Community Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42989471/4788546) for an example.

---

#### Update *#0*

Installed (on *20190930*) latest patch (***v2019.2.3***), and **the traceback is present** in *PyCharm*'s console (so, the bug is fixed).

Comment: Thanks. This is the correct answer I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome!. Mondays when I reboot my laptop, I check for updates for my currently installed apps, and I usually update them. Thanks to your question I didn't upgrade *PyCharm*. and I won't, till this will be fixed. It doesn't bother me very much (as I don't rely much on this feature), but still :) .

Comment: The fix is now integrated in the EAP version `2019.3 EAP build 193.3519.27` and hence will also be part of `PyCharm v2019.3`

Answer (score 0):

did you check your whitespaces at start of each executable line? one time it occured to me was fixed after just correcting the whitespaces.

Comment: Definitely doesn't have to do anything with whitespace. I can run the exact same program in an older PyCharm and it works as expected.