# After I convert PY to EXE using PyInstaller it throw error

Tags: python, kivy, typeerror, pyinstaller

after I converted my PY file to EXE and I ran it, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PrngCipher.py", line 2, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "kivy\__init__.py", line 272, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py", line 71, in _pyi_pkgutil_iter_modules
    assert pkg_path.startswith(SYS_PREFIX)
TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not PureWindowsPath
```

I'm new to Python and PyInstaller, I don't know what this error is about, I followed many tutorials and hooked the right dependencies into the .spec file but it still broke.
My .py, .kv and .spec file:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1F7I4xEphB3d2ErDPs7vGDpT7trTmHKgC?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did more research and looked into the upper lines of the error message and I found out the problem was at the PyInstaller pakage's code not my code, the fix is to downgrade PyInstaller to 4.3 waiting for a fix using `python -m pip install PyInstaller==4.3` and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you are using `startsWith` with wrong parameter types, notably, it expects a `String` to be the first parameter, while you pass `PureWindowsPath` instead. I'm not a Python specialist, but I believe that you could solve it via calling `.__str__()` for the variable that you aim to pass, so its value will be represented as a `String` when being passed to `startsWith`.

Comment: I don't know what is the `startsWith` so I can't really debug which part it was in my code, thank you for simplifying the error message though

Answer (score 0):

It's a regression bug in *PyInstaller 4.4*: [[GitHub]: pyinstaller/pyinstaller - TypeError: startswith first arg must be a str or tuple of str, not PurePosixPath](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6018). 
It was already fixed (by **[[GitHub]: pyinstaller/pyinstaller - hooks: pkgutil rthook: declare SYS_PREFIX as function-local symbol](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/6019)**), but the fix will only be available in the next release, which (considering the bug severity) should be available soon.

Ways to go further:

- Downgrade *PyInstaller* to *v4.3*, which doesn't have this bug: per [[SO]: After I convert PY to EXE using PyInstaller it throw error (@MinecraftPlays's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68428322/after-i-convert-py-to-exe-using-pyinstaller-it-throw-error/68470337#68470337). 
  The simplest one
- Wait until next *PyInstaller* version (*4.5*?) becomes available and upgrade it then. 
  Not acceptable (most likely)
- Apply the fix manually to your *PyInstaller* installation (as it's just one file). Check [[SO]: Run / Debug a Django application's UnitTests from the mouse right click context menu in PyCharm Community Edition? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989471/run-debug-a-django-applications-unittests-from-the-mouse-right-click-context-me/42989490#42989490) (**Patching *utrunner*** section) for how to apply patches (on *Win*). 
  Developer approach

Comment: Moved the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68562958/typeerror-in-opening-an-exe-file.