# TypeError in opening an exe file

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, exe

My python kivy code works without errors, I'm transforming .py in. exe using the command

```
pyinstaller -F BooruScraperUltra.py
```

The conversion goes without errors, but when I try to open the. exe file, the following error comes out:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vpL6.png (I apologize for the quality of the photo)

I am using Windows 7, PyInstaller 4.4, Python 3.8.
Please help me solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to downgrade PyInstaller to 4.3. The command is python -m pip install PyInstaller==4.3