# Kivy app failed to execute after packaging with pyinstaller.It says failed to execute script due to unhandled exception

Tags: kivy, pyinstaller

Here is the exception after running exe file packaged by pyinstaller from kivy app on windows 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "try.py", line 1, in

```
     import kivy
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
   File "kivy\__init__.py", line 272, in <module>
   File "Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py", line 71, in _pyi_pkgutil_iter_modules
 TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not PureWindowsPath
[6292] Failed to execute script 'try' due to unhandled exception!
```

And here is my try.py (Kivy app)
'''

```
import kivy
kivy.require('2.0.0') # replace with your current kivy version !
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color,Ellipse,Line
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        color=(random(),1.,1.)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color,mode="hsv")
            d=30.
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x-d/2,touch.y-d/2),size=(d,d))
            touch.ud['line']=Line(points=(touch.x,touch.y))
    def on_touch_move(self,touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points+=[touch.x,touch.y]

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent=Widget()
        self.painter=MyPaintWidget()
        clearbtn=Button(text="Clear")
        clearbtn.bind(on_release=self.clear_canvas)
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        parent.add_widget(clearbtn)
        return parent
    def clear_canvas(self,obj):
        self.painter.canvas.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

'''
Below  is my  try.spec file,with kivy_deps and glew added

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy_deps import sdl2,glew

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\25670\\kivy_venv\\try.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\25670\\Desktop\\app'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,Tree('C:\\Users\\25670\\kivy_venv\\'),
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins+glew.dep_bins)],
          name='try',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

I will be glad if you help me solve this problem it is ruining my life.Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your .spec file? Did it work at some point?

Comment: I have added the try.spec file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After I convert PY to EXE using PyInstaller it throw error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68428322/after-i-convert-py-to-exe-using-pyinstaller-it-throw-error)