# XLCALL.LIB for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, excel, vba, xll

We recently migrated to Visual Studio 2013 from VS2010. One of the project generates .xll using XLCALL32.lib and XLCALL dll. Now after migration to Visual Studio 2013, I am getting an error

```
lnk2026 module unsafe for safeseh image
```

There are some solutions available of disbaling SAFESEH from here:
[module unsafe for SAFESEH image C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599940/module-unsafe-for-safeseh-image-c)

But following this solution, Excel throws exception and crashes, while same code works fine when build on Visual Studio 2010.

I am wondering if XLCALL32.LIB is separately available for VC120 build tools.